# Shuffle instruction in CUDA not working

Tags: c++, cuda, shuffle

I have got problem with shuffle instruction in CUDA 5.0.

This is snippet of my kernel. It is inside the loop. Print is there only for debug purpose because I can't use ordinary debugger:

```
...
tex_val = tex2D(srcTexRef, threadIdx.x + w, y_pos);
if (threadIdx.x == 0)
{
    left = left_value[y_pos];
}
else
{
    printf("thread %d; shfl value: %f \n", threadIdx.x, __shfl_up(value, 1));
    left = __shfl_up(value, 1);
}

printf("thread %d; value: %f; tex_val: %f; left: %f \n", threadIdx.x, value, tex_val, left);
...
```

From that I get this output:

```
l0:  ITERATION 1
l1:  thread 0; value: 0; tex_val: 1; left: 4
l2: 
l3:  ITERATION 2
l4:  thread 1; shfl value: 0
l5:  thread 0; value: 5; tex_val: 1; left: 5
l6:  thread 1; value: 0; tex_val: 1; left: 0
l7: 
l8:  ITERATION 3
l9:  thread 1; shfl value: 0
l10: thread 2; shfl value: 1
l11: thread 0; value: 6; tex_val: 1; left: 6
l12: thread 1; value: 1; tex_val: 1; left: 0
l13: thread 2; value: 2; tex_val: 1; left: 1
...
```

From the output I can see that thread 1 doesn't get value from thread 0 in any iteration even though I can clearly see that it has value (line 4 - shfl value is 0; line 5 - value is 5). Thread 2 and higher can get value from lower thread. Where am I making mistake? Is it happening because of the branching?

Comment: This is question concerning my project to school. I don't have nvidia graphic card so I have to do this project on campus computer and I don't have administrator rights to it, hence no nvidia debugger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's because of the branching. Quoting from the [CUDA programming guide B.14.2](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#warp-shuffle-functions):

> The `__shfl()` intrinsics permit exchanging of a variable between threads within a warp without use of shared memory. The exchange occurs simultaneously for all **active** threads within the warp, ...

and

> Threads may only read data from another thread which is actively participating in the `__shfl()` command. If the target thread is inactive, the retrieved value is undefined.

In a branch, active threads are those taking the same path of execution, while those taking different ones are inactive. In your case, thread 0 is inactive, so you cannot shuffle from it.

Comment: Thank you. I read that, but I missunderstood when the thread is active and when not.