# Warp shuffling for CUDA

Tags: cuda, shuffle, ptx, gpu-warp

I need to make a warp shuffling that look like this:
[image: warp shuffling]

On this picture, the number of threads is limited to `8` to make it readable.
If I read the Nvidia SDK and ptx manual, the shuffle instruction should do the job, specially the `shfl.idx.b32 d[|p], a, b, c;` ptx instruction.

From the [manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html) I read:

```
Each thread in the currently executing warp will compute a source lane
index j based on input operands b and c and the mode. If the computed
source lane index j is in range, the thread will copy the input operand
a from lane j into its own destination register d;
```

So, providing proper values of `b` and `c`, I should be able to do it by writing a function like this (inspired from CUDA SDK `__shufl` primitive implementation).

```
  __forceinline__ __device __ float shuffle(float var){
   float ret;
   int srcLane = ???
   int c = ???
   asm volatile ("shfl.idx.b32 %0, %1, %2, %3;" : "=f"(ret) : "f"(var), "r"(srcLane), "r"(c));
  return ret;
```

}

If it is possible, what is the constant for `srcLane` and `c`? I am not able to determine them (I am using CUDA 8.0) .

Best,

Timocafe

Comment: What is the point in writing your own `shuffle` function that calls the ptx `shfl`? If i see this correctly your problem can be solved by calling the normal `__shufl` primitive with the correct parameters.

Comment: I was confuse by the __shufl reading documentation I just found instruction to make a a broadcast and not a shuffle. But you are write it is really better to us it directly,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend doing this with the [CUDA intrinsic](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-shuffle-functions) rather than with PTX (or inline ASM).  However the following code demonstrates both methods:

```cpp
// cat t54.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void k(){
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    int j = i;
    if (i<4) j*=2;
    if ((i>3) && (i<8)) j-=(7-i);
    int k = __shfl_sync(0x0FFU, i+100, j);
    printf("lane: %d, result: %d\n", i, k);
}

__forceinline__ __device__ float shuffle(float var, int lane){
    float ret;
    int srcLane = lane;
    int c = 0x1F;
    asm volatile ("shfl.idx.b32 %0, %1, %2, %3;" : "=f"(ret) : "f"(var), "r"(srcLane), "r"(c));
    return ret;
}

__global__ void k1(){
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    int j = i;
    if (i<4) j*=2;
    if ((i>3) && (i<8)) j-=(7-i);
    float k = shuffle((float)(i+100), j);
    printf("lane: %d, result: %f\n", i, k);
}


int main(){
    k<<<1,8>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    k1<<<1,8>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t54 t54.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t54
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
lane: 0, result: 100
lane: 1, result: 102
lane: 2, result: 104
lane: 3, result: 106
lane: 4, result: 101
lane: 5, result: 103
lane: 6, result: 105
lane: 7, result: 107
lane: 0, result: 100.000000
lane: 1, result: 102.000000
lane: 2, result: 104.000000
lane: 3, result: 106.000000
lane: 4, result: 101.000000
lane: 5, result: 103.000000
lane: 6, result: 105.000000
lane: 7, result: 107.000000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Using the CUDA intrinsic (the first method) the only real task is to compute the source lane index.  Based on your pattern I wrote some code to do that and put it in the variable `j`.

Answer (score 1):

Robert has already and satisfactorily answered this question. I had implemented the code below, showing permutation of a full warp.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort = true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) { getchar(); exit(code); }
    }
}

__global__ void shufflingKernel(double *d_data, double *d_result, int *d_perm){

    unsigned mask = __activemask(); 
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    int srcLane = d_perm[tid];
    double var = d_data[tid];
    //d_result[tid] = __shfl_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, var, srcLane);
    d_result[tid] = __shfl_sync(mask, var, srcLane);
}

int main(){

    const int N = 32;

    double h_data[32] = { 3.4, 42.2, 2., -1., 10., 11., 2., -1., 10., 33., 2.3, 11., 44., 0., -33., -21.,
        4.4, 43.2, 3., -2., 13., 15., 222., -90., 17., 30., 11.3, 7., 22., 100., -30., -91. };
    double *h_result = (double *)malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    int h_perm[32] = { 6, 11, 9, 2, 5, 23, 31, 0, 3, 27, 29, 1, 28, 30, 17, 13, 10, 8, 4, 22, 7, 18, 24, 12, 20,
        19, 16, 26, 21, 15, 25, 14 };

    int *d_perm; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_perm, N * sizeof(int)));
    double *d_data; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_data, N * sizeof(double)));
    double *d_result; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_result, N * sizeof(double)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_perm, &h_perm[0], N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_data, &h_data[0], N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    shufflingKernel << <1, 32>> >(d_data, d_result, d_perm);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_result, d_result, N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        printf("k = %d; Original = %f; New = %f; Check = %f\n", k, h_data[k], h_result[k], h_data[h_perm[k]]);
    }

}
```

Notice that, instead of using `0xFFFFFFFF` for the mask of active threads, it is safer using the warp-level primitive `__activemask()` in the sense of [Shuffle instruction in CUDA not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095899/shuffle-instruction-in-cuda-not-working).

Answer (score -2):

What you are trying to do in your `shuffle` operation is to be able to have dynamically index source lanes on which shuffle operates. One needs to understand that any variation of `shuffle` command (`__shfl, __shfl_up, __shfl_down, __shfl_xor`) needs a constant value for its second parameter and this parameter is the **same** for all lanes within a warp. You can play with grouping of threads within a warp by specifying `width`. Thus, for example, by specifying

```
float var = ...
__shfl_xor(var, 3, 4);
```

the lane permutation will look like:

```
0 1 2 3
   |
3 2 1 0
```

So, to answer your question, it's not possible to do it with a single `__shuffle` operation of any kind. But you can implement it by combining several `__shuffle` commands with different second parameters.

Comment: This is not correct.  The source lane parameter need not be the same for all lanes within the warp.  Indexed shuffle for example is an **any-to-any** operation, see slide 4 [here](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3174-Kepler-Shuffle-Tips-Tricks.pdf). My answer demonstrates how the operation may be achieved with a single shuffle.